# HTTP Delete Request on a tomcat server

Tags: java, rest, http

I'm trying to delete a class given its id number from a tomcat server. I did some research on DELETE request where some sources were saying it's similar to the POST request. So, I changed my code accordingly, however I still get an error code 404.

My controller has a delete mapping with @DeleteMapping("/classes/{cId}") and here's my code to delete a class based on its id number.

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/classes/{cId}");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter wr = new 
OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.write("{\"cId\":" + cId + "}");
wr.flush();
wr.close();
connection.connect();
connection.disconnect();
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? How would I change my code to successfully delete a class?

Comment: I think you missed the context path in your web service URL. Are you able to hit above web-service URL using postman?

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite understand what you mean. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm saying try to request the URL using postman application. I think your URL is incorrect. Postman download link : https://www.getpostman.com/downloads

Comment: You are not actually setting the ID that you want to delete are you? The {cId} needs to be replaced by the id of the class you want to delete.

Comment: @ophychius It's given an id in the line where I'm writing using the OuputStreamWriter unless I'm doing it wrong